# Where do find the check constraint information within the information_schema on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, information-schema

I am using SQL Server for an application. I have a column called `FieldOptions` in my database. This column behaves like `enum` column in MySQL. Here is the query I would execute to recreate this column on a table called `TableName`.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName 
ADD FieldsOptions VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL 
    CHECK (FieldsOptions IN ('Useful', 'Useless', 'Unknown'))
```

Now, I want to be able to query the `information_schema` table to obtain the valid values. In addition to the column information, I want to see `'Useful', 'Useless', 'Unknown'`

I check the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table and also `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` but found no info that provides with with the valid options.

How can I get the valid values for my column?

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag as not being relevant to your direct question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select definition 
from sys.check_constraints 
where name = (select cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
              from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu
              inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS c on c.CONSTRAINT_NAME=cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
              where COLUMN_NAME = 'FieldsOptions<Your Column Name>')
```